# Java applying multiply to each item in an array

Tags: java

Alright, so I'm trying to create a "sales tax program' where the user can input the items and it adds it to an array, called "costArray".  I only know how to do it, almost, with a String (since I need costArray.length for the loop) but I'm kind of lost.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction so I can: Take an array of numbers (doubles) and apply a multiplier to it (0.08 for sales tax percentage) and output a total number (double)?  Here is what I have so far, can you tell me if I'm close?  Thanks!:

> ```
> public class Input
>  {
>  private Scanner keybd;
>  private String item;
>  private double cost;
>  private String[] costArray;
>  private String[] itemArray;
>  /**
>   * Constructor for objects of class Scanner
>   */
> public Input(int anyAmountofItems)
> {
>     keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
>     costArray = new String[anyAmountofItems];
>     itemArray = new String[anyAmountofItems];
> }
> /**
>  * Mutator method to set the item names and costs
>  */
> public void setArray(){
>     for(int index=0; index < itemArray.length; index++){ 
>     System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
>     itemArray[index] = keybd.next();}
>     for(int indexa=0; indexa < itemArray.length; indexa++){
>         System.out.println(itemArray[indexa]);
>     }
>     for(int indexb=0; indexb < costArray.length; indexb++){ 
>     System.out.println("Enter the item cost: ");
>     costArray[indexb] = keybd.next();}
>     for(int indexc=0; indexc < costArray.length; indexc++){
>         System.out.println(costArray[indexc]);
>     }
>     }
>     /**
>      * Accessor method to return the items cost with tax
>      */
>     public double getTax(){
>         return costArray.length;
>     }
>     //         /**
>     //          * Mutator method to calculate tax on each item
>     //          */
>     //         public void calculateTax(){
>     //             for(int index=0; index < costArray.length; index++){
>     //                 System.out.println(0.08 * costArray[index]);
>     //             }
>     //         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The number ist stored in a String and you have to "convert" it to a real number (a double value)

The way to do it is shown here:

```
 String s = "-1.234";
 double value = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

double taxCoef = 0.08;
double[] prices = {10,20,30};
double total = DoubleStream.of(prices).map(p->p*(1+taxCoef)).sum();

System.out.println(total);
```

output: `64.80000000000001`

(alternatively, can sum up first and then multiply)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are a bad idea, if you don't know before which size they will have. Why not use an ArrayList? If you don't know it right know: You'll really will need it often!

Names of indexes inside a loop are well with 'i', 'n', 'p, q, r' or 'x', and they only exist in their own loop, so you can define a new 'i' in the second loop - no need for indexa, indexb, ... .

For learning, a double might be sufficient, but in real world, you shouldn't use double for Money amounts, but BigDecimal. The bit-representation of fractions leads else to surprising effects.

And Scanner has already methods like scanner.nextDouble () to read a Number.